# how to close NzNotificationService notification popup

Tags: angular, notifications, ng-zorro-antd

I am using [NG-ZORRO Notification](https://ng.ant.design/components/notification/en)

I have an angular code

```
this.notif = this.notification.create(
   'success',
   'Notification',
   'test message'
);
```

I could not find any api like `.close()`

But the notification shows for 4 seconds, within that duration the user performed another action

Therefore I want to close it, any idea we can force close it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you linked mention `Methods for destruction are also provided:`

and then they say to use:

```
NzNotificationService.remove(id)
// Remove the notification with the specified id. When the id is empty, remove all notifications (the notification id is returned by the create method)
```